# nginx passenger standalone prevent proxy_pass on subdirectory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, proxypass

i'm running nginx as reverse proxy for passenger standalone rails server.
I need to set up root `/` location on passenger standalone port (5000) but few other subdirectories must be served by "pure" nginx.
I'm trying configurations like

```
server {
    listen 443;

    root /path/to/rails/public;

    server_name example.com;

    ssl on;
    # ... some ssl config

    # this is used for passenger standalone on port 5000
    location / {
            proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:5000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_buffering off;
    }

    # this is not passenger standalone! 
    location /subdir {
            proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1;
            auth_basic "Restricted access area authorization needed.";
            auth_basic_user_file /path/to/.htpasswd;
    }
```

}

but https://example.com/subdir/ return always 404 error.
Any tips to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Move the location directive for `/subdir` above the root location's direction.
The request paths are matched in the order defined in the configuration.

```
server {
    listen 443;

    root /path/to/rails/public;

    server_name example.com;

    ssl on;
    # ... some ssl config

    # this is not passenger standalone! 
    location /subdir {
            proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1;
            auth_basic "Restricted access area authorization needed.";
            auth_basic_user_file /path/to/.htpasswd;
    }
    # this is used for passenger standalone on port 5000
    location / {
            proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:5000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_buffering off;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @aBadAssCowboy thank you for your reply. I've already tried to move location /subdir before location / but doesn't work. I suppose that location /subdir statement is not correct.